# matlab constant anonymous function returns only one value instead of an array

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I've been searching the net for a couple of mornings and found nothing, hope you can help.

I have an anonymous function like this

```
f = @(x,y) [sin(2*pi*x).*cos(2*pi*y), cos(2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*y)];
```

that needs to be evaluated on an array of points, something like

```
x = 0:0.1:1;
y = 0:0.1:1;
w = f(x',y');
```

Now, in the above example everything works fine, the result w is a 11x2 matrix with in each row the correct value f(x(i), y(i)).
The problem comes when I change my function to have constant values:

```
f = @(x,y) [0, 1];
```

Now, even with array inputs like before, I only get out a 1x2 array like w = [0,1];
while of course I want to have the same structure as before, i.e. a 11x2 matrix.

I have no idea why Matlab is doing this...

EDIT 1
Sorry, I thought it was pretty clear from what I wrote in the original question, but I see some of you asking, so here is a clarification: what I want is to have again a 11x2 matrix, since I am feeding the function with arrays with 11 elements.
This means I expect to have an output exactly like in the first example, just with changed values in it: a matrix with 11 rows and 2 columns, with only values 0 in the first column and only values 1 in the second, since for all x(i) and y(i) the answer should be the vector [0,1].
It means I expect to have:

```
w = [0 1
     0 1
     0 1
     ...
     0 1]
```

seems pretty natural to me...

Comment: Why would you expect `@(x,y) [0, 1]` to return enything else but `[0,1]`?????

Comment: i have updated the question with a clarification

Comment: I have no idea why this is downvoted. I think that this is a totally reasonable question for someone coming to Matlab form a more mathematical background.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Although I have used Matlab for a number of years now, sometimes I still fail to comprehend the way it behaves sometimes. But now I get why this was not working, the point is in how matlab uses vector-input arguments, which is just different from what I imagined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a function `f = @(x,y) [0, 1];` which has the input parameters x,y and the output `[0,1]`. What else do you expect to happen?

Update:

This should match your description:

```
g=@(x,y)[zeros(size(x)),ones(size(y))]
g(x',y')
```

Comment: yeah thank you... I thought matlab would return a value the same size of the inputs by default, but now i think i'm starting to see the flaw in my reasoning. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Defining an anonymous function `f` as

```
f = @(x,y) [0,1];
```

naturally returns `[0,1]` for any inputs `x` and `y` regardless of the length of those vectors.

This behavior puzzled me also until I realized that I expected `f(a,b)` to loop over `a` and `b` as if I had written

```
for inc = 1:length(a)
    f(a(inc), b(inc))
end
```

However, `f(a,b)` does not loop over the length of its inputs, so it merely returns `[0,1]` regardless of the length of `a` and `b`.

The desired behavior can be obtained by defining `f` as

```
g=@(x,y)[zeros(size(x)),ones(size(y))]
```

as Daniel stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19616713/10708121).