# Evaluating a constant anonymous function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function-handle

In Matlab, I generally do things such as

```
f  = @(x) x.^2;
xx = 0:.1:1;
ff = f(xx);
```

So that f is a function handle and both xx and ff are 1x11 vectors.

However, if for some reason I need to define my function handle f like this

```
f  = @(x) 1;
```

and do not change the code for xx and ff, then xx will still be a vector but ff will NOT: it will be a double.

This is annoying of course, because the sequel of my code assumes that ff is a 11x1 vector, so I would need to change my code any time f happens to be constant.

So my first question is whether or not my code is sound to begin with.
If so, what should I do to make it work in the "constant f" case?
If not, how should I rewrite it?

This is admittedly similar to
[matlab constant anonymous function returns only one value instead of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616619/matlab-constant-anonymous-function-returns-only-one-value-instead-of-an-array)
but I can't quite find an answer in that thread.

Comment: Don't you just need `f=@(x) ones(size(x));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minor modification of the answer you linked will provide the required result:

```
f = @(x) ones(size(x));
```

The size of `f(x)` will match the size of the input `x` since `f` outputs a vector of ones the same size as `x`.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but isn't there another way around?

Comment: @Tom why should there be? You want your function to return a vector, which is the same size as `x` but contains only the value 1. That *is exactly* `ones(size(x))`.

Comment: @Tom I don't see why you'd need something else. The `ones(size(x))` is a generalization of your original approach, since in MATLAB `1` is by most practical purposes equal to `ones(1)`.

Answer (score -2):

I found a better way of doing this. This shows how stupid Matlab is:

```
f  = @(x) (x-x)+1
```

Try it!